# How to put figure inside algorithm environment?

Tags: tables, graphics, algorithms

I am trying to put figure inside the algorithm environment and also a table. But getting error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}    % For margin alignment
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{arevmath}     % For math symbols
 \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

 \title{Algorithm template}
 \author{Moody}

 \date{\today}    % Today's date

 \begin{document}
 \maketitle
 \section{Demo code}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Put your caption here}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]

        \Procedure{Tom}{$a,b$}       \Comment{This is a test}
        \State System Initialization
        \State Read the value 
        \If{$condition = True$}
        \State Do this
        \If{$Condition \geq 1$}
        \State Do that
        \ElsIf{$Condition \neq 5$}
        \State Do another
        \State Do that as well
        \Else
        \State \includegraphics[scale=1.5]{lion.jpg}

        \EndIf
        \EndIf

        \While{$something \not= 0$}  \Comment{put some comments here}
        \State $var1 \leftarrow var2$  \Comment{another comment}
        \State $var3 \leftarrow var4$
        \EndWhile  \label{roy's loop}
        \EndProcedure

    \end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

In your provided `MWE`, you didn't include the package `graphicx`, just include that package your `MWE` works fine for me, and the modified `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}    % For margin alignment
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{arevmath}     % For math symbols
 \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

If still the `error` exists, then please place the error code too...